# Creating Text boxes issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have posted a previous question but there was little help so I tried to start coding it and looking up some more on my own and I'm stuck on some code. I'm trying to follow MVVM

**I have created a Class called `Standard` which looks like this:**

```
namespace MVVModel
{
    public class Standard
    {

        string _title;
        string _question;



        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        public string Question
        {
            get { return _question; }
            set { _question = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Then I created `ViewModel` class which looks like this:**

```
namespace MVVModel
{
    class ViewModel
    {

        ObservableCollection<Standard> _title = new ObservableCollection<Standard>();
        ObservableCollection<Standard> _question = new ObservableCollection<Standard>();

    public ViewModel()
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Standard> Title
    {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
            }
     }

     public ObservableCollection<Standard> Question
     {
            get
            {
                return _question;
            }
            set
            {
                _question = value;
            }
     }
     }
}
```

**Here is my XAML:**

```
<Grid>

    <Button x:Name="btnTitle" Content="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="691,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnQuestion" Content="Question" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="797,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding AddTitle}"/>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Question}" Margin="0,86,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

I just want to create a textbox dynamically but nothing it showing, any help?

Comment: You must first accept the previous answer, if it helped you.

Comment: How many Questions are in your list? If you did not insert any, there will be no textbox.

Comment: You need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your classes. However, you really shouldn't add duplicate questions... instead, you should edit your original question.

Comment: @nvoigt Firstly, they should be able to add as many questions and titles as they want.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Sorry will accept it now.

Comment: @user3157821 if there are none in the list, you will have zero textboxes. Your code generates one textbox per question in your list.

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry if I'm being thick, but I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mentioned in my previous answer about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Why you again need a collection of Questions and Titles in your viewModel, this already exists in the Standard class.

You need a collection of Standard class in your main ViewModel. Thats what I get from your question if I have understood it correctly.

Here is the implementation for INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class Standard : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
      protected void NotifyOfPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }

      protected void NotifyOfPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty> property)
      {
          NotifyOfPropertyChanged(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
      }

    string _title;
    ObservableCollection<string> _questions;        

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { 
            _title = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged(()=>Title);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Questions
    {
        get { return _questions; }
        set { 
            _questions = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged(()=>Questions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have looked through your previous answer. It says That `NofityPropertyChanged` needs a namespace? also the XAML says that `Text` is already defined?

Comment: You need to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Ok, Let me do

Comment: Thanks for the edit, `protected void NotifyOfPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property)` The `TProperty` has an error saying `It could not be found`. Also in that same method `property.GetMemberInfo` The `GetMemberInfo` says `System.Linq.Expressions does not contain a definition for GetMemberInfo` Finally, the lambda expressions wont convert to string.

Comment: You need to add respective reference into your project.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, its just the `NotifyOfPropertyChanged(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);` GetMemberInfo that is still erroring.

Comment: As I mentioned you need to add respective namespace and references to your project all those dll required. System.Reflection

Comment: Which ones, I have looked Around and added Reflection and also DLL the LINQ Data but its still not coming up

Answer (score 0):

You must follow a couple of steps to accomplish this task.

1. First you need to bind the collection of `Standard` to the `Grid`, in place of `Question`.
2. Second you need to bind a property of the previous class to the textbox.

Ex:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Question"} />
</DataTemplate>
```

Edit:

I would like to mention this article to help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: Firstly, when I bind `Standard` to the `Grid` what property do I do it with as `<Grid Command="{}">` and `<Grid ItemSource="{}">` doesn't work. Secondly, I get an error your piece of code `Question is not supported in WPF project`

Comment: You dont need the Command. I attached a Quick Tutorial, to help you. I think that is best to you to follow a complete tutorial and grab some experience in place of a simple question/answer.

Comment: I have had a look through the tutorial and downloaded it to see how it works and I understand it a bit better now. In there `ViewModel` it will be different to mine as I just want to create a `Textbox`, what would I add in here?